# Reason to choose TFS over Svn/Jenkins/Jira

Tags: svn, version-control, tfs, continuous-integration, jenkins

I'm aware that there are a lot of questions on SO with similar content, but I can assure you that I have read the most of them completely with answers and comments.

My situation is slightly different in means that our company is mostly Java-oriented and thus the standard ALM tool set is already set up:

- SVN for Source Control
- Jira for task/issue tracking
- Jenkins for continuous integration

Now, I run a team of .NET developers and we need to set up something similar for our dev process and the discussion is whether to go separately with TFS or to reuse the existing infrastructure and plug in the .NET projects there as well.

I realize that the biggest pro-TFS argument is good integration with VS, but with our current setup I am wondering if there are some good arguments for not using TFS at all.

Comment: http://jamesmckay.net/2011/02/team-foundation-server-is-the-lotus-notes-of-version-control-tools/ (and the linked survey) plus http://www.derekhammer.com/2011/09/11/tfs-is-destroying-your-development-capacity.html suggest TFS is not a good idea. If you're wanting to switch VCS, if anything, I would go for git. I switched from SVN to git and can't imagine returning to SVN. In any case, all these systems integrate fine with Jenkins.

Comment: I didn't wanted to include git in the picture, but yes, i am also looking ahead of using git in the near future which is another reason not going the TFS route. Thx for the links though, they seem to be quite useful.

Comment: Christopher's linked blog is a very interesting read.  I'm generally an advocate of TFS and don't particularly agree with many of the statements in james' blog (like some of the listed limitations of TFS), HOWEVER in this case I'd select Svn/Jenkins/Jira over TFS purely from a uniformity/maintenace perspective.  I think that's a compelling argument all by itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As someone who is using both SVN and TFS for .NET developmnet, here are the biggest reasons to choose SVN over TFS in my opinion:

1. TFS licenses are expensive. SVN ranges from cheap to free. You can install VisualSVN server with free standard license and use it commercially (http://www.visualsvn.com/server/licensing/) or pay for the enterprise version for under $1000.
2. One thing I've had happen several times in TFS is what I'd call the lost update. I've checked in a change, it doesn't make it to the rest of the team for some reason unknown to me. This seems to happen at least once every couple months or so. I've yet to have this happen in SVN.
3. TFS seems to get unnecessarily complicated if you choose to operate in a disconnected way. For some reason if you operate offline, it goes ahead and checks out config files for no apparent reason. SVN is disconnected, so it doesn't care. It's always offline.
4. Choice of integration level with Visual Studio - If I want to go to Windows Explorer to check in my changes or get latest, I can, with something like TortoiseSVN. If I want to integrate with Visual Studio, I can use something like AnkhSVN (my personal favorite). Granted, the TFS PowerTools have made this argument lest potent, as they now have Shell integration there as well, but I still like TortoiseSVN better.

Bottom line, I've found SVN to be cheaper to operate, more stable, and definitely more mature.

Comment: i am looking ofrward to more answers like this one. not because they are con-TFS, but because are answered by developers who experienced both platforms. thx.

Comment: #2 is not a TFS exception, #3 just isn't true it's easier than SVN to manage, not to mention SVN's limited merges as compared to TFS. Why would any check in view explorer? Probably because they don't TDD or unit tes for that matter. TFS is more mature and stable.....It appears that you haven't used TFS for anything other than a file storage or you would be a little more knowledgable, or you're just biased. I've used both and TFS is lightning speeads better for both source control and life cycle management

Comment: Honestly, if you pay attention to what I wrote, I was specific in #3 about using TFS in a disconnected scenario, and it was definitely true at the time. Microsoft has since added local workspaces that seem to resolve that issue, although it's not the default setup. 

As for your assertion that I haven't used TFS for anything but file storage, you're wrong. When I wrote this, I was in the middle of a project where we were using TFS for Agile project management, including TDD and automated builds. If you've never experienced #2, I suppose you're lucky, but the issue was common to our team.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Visual Studio Team System (VSTS) is a complete development environment for mostly Windows oriented development. TFS is at the heart of the system and plays a key role getting complete tracebility from requirement to final system test.

[image: Visual Studio Team System 2008]

So one of the most important reasons to use TFS as Version Control System is because it play this central role in VSTS, allows this traceability and simply does the job. You might not want to call any of the VSTS components best of breed individually, but together they provide a seamless integrated CI development environment out of the box with *a greater total than the sum of components*.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @kroonwijk, but the way i see it, exactly the version control system is the weakest link in the whole TFS stack. I don't think that i would like to wait for another 3-5 years for MS to come up with distributed version control system, while using Subversion i have no limitation of choosing any other VCS at any time.

Answer (score 1):

If your team uses visual studio you basically get VS Team Services for free, which is include a lot of TFS functionalities for free for small teams. On top of that you get free credits on azure every month and are set on the infrastructure side to start. Resuming, you don't need a TFS license if you already have a visual studio subscription to do most of the things involved in developing an application.